# ipad - autofocussing textbox

Tags: ipad, html

I have a requirement to set the focus to a textbox in a page when the page loads. My target device is ipad.

I heard that, by design, it is not supported in ipad.

But is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://www.quora.com/Mobile-Safari-iPhone-or-iPad-with-JavaScript-how-can-I-launch-the-on-screen-keyboard) can help you:

> By design, some `focus()` events in Mobile Safari are ignored. A lot of sites would do `focus()` unnecessarily and bringing up the keyboard is slow/intrusive.